# DJANGO PWA Install to home screen not working

Tags: django, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I am trying to follow the instructions on this site (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Add_to_home_screen) with my DJANGO app to make a PWA "Install to home screen' button.

I have SSL installed on the site, and it seems to me that the service worker is installed properly, I got the "Service Worker Registered" message back. However when I click the button nothing happens, the + sign does not appear in the URL bar as it should.

I have no idea what is causing the error, as there is no clear sign of anything not working properly.

My index.html:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>A2HS demo</title>
    <link href="{% static 'css/index.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="{% static 'js/index.js' %}" defer></script>
    <link rel="manifest" href="{% static 'manifest.json' %}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="add-button">Add to home screen</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

My manifest.json:

```
{
  "short_name": "Test site",
  "name": "Test site",
  "theme_color": "#062440",
  "background_color": "#F7F8F9",
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/logo.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/index.html"
}
```

My index.js

```
// Register service worker to control making site work offline
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register('/static/js/service-worker.js')
    .then(() => { console.log('Service Worker Registered'); });
}
// Code to handle install prompt on desktop
let deferredPrompt;
const addBtn = document.querySelector('.add-button');
addBtn.style.display = 'none';

window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
  // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
  e.preventDefault();
  // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
  deferredPrompt = e;
  // Update UI to notify the user they can add to home screen
  addBtn.style.display = 'block';

  addBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // hide our user interface that shows our A2HS button
    addBtn.style.display = 'none';
    // Show the prompt
    deferredPrompt.prompt();
    // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
    deferredPrompt.userChoice.then((choiceResult) => {
      if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
        console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt');
      } else {
        console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt');
      }
      deferredPrompt = null;
    });
  });
});
```

And my service-worker.js:

```
self.addEventListener('install', (e) => {
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open('fox-store').then((cache) => cache.addAll([
      '/index.html',
      '/static/css/index.css',
      '/static/js/index.js',
    ])),
  );
});
self.addEventListener('fetch', (e) => {
  console.log(e.request.url);
  e.respondWith(
    caches.match(e.request).then((response) => response || fetch(e.request)),
  );
});
```

Comment: looks like you are throwing an error with this right before your index.js. Perhaps try commenting the line out. $('body').ihavecookies(options);